# Php find image src in file

Tags: php, html, arrays

Hi I have this code that lists all directories and then gets the content from the `h1` with the `id` header.

But I can't seem to find a way to find the first `img src` in the file as well.

```
$directory="./photos";
$sortOrder="newestFirst";

   $results = array();
   $handler = opendir($directory);

while ($file = readdir($handler)) { 
       if ($file != '.' && $file != '..'){
           $currentModified = filectime($directory."/".$file);
           $file_names[] = $file;
           $file_dates[] = $currentModified;
       }   
   }
       closedir($handler);

   //Sort the date array by preferred order
   if ($sortOrder == "newestFirst"){
       arsort($file_dates);
   }else{
       asort($file_dates);
   }

   //Match file_names array to file_dates array
   $file_names_Array = array_keys($file_dates);
   foreach ($file_names_Array as $idx => $name) $name=$file_names[$name];
   $file_dates = array_merge($file_dates);

   $i = 0;

   //Loop through dates array and then echo the list
   foreach ($file_dates as $$file_dates){
       $date = $file_dates;
       $j = $file_names_Array[$i];
       $file = $file_names[$j];
       $i++;

       $doc = new DOMDocument; 
        $doc->loadHTMLFile('./photos/'.$file.'/index.html'); 
        $node = $doc->getElementById('content'); 

       echo  '<a href="./photos/'.$file.'/index.html">'.$node->nodeValue.'</a><br />';  
   }
```

Anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking.  Have you looked into Glob? http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_glob.asp

Comment: Isn't `$doc`empty?  double-check that.

Comment: **http://www.w3fools.com/**...  Try instead THIS link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: the hole php script is working. But i need to a the ability to find the first image src in the file wich the other code finds

Comment: the index.html in each directory wich the script finds. contains a H1 and a couple of images. I need to finde the src of the first....

Comment: can you use jquery or javascript to run a function on the page in addition to the php?

Comment: i could but the files a not include in the file how run the script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want the first image in this section:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->loadHTMLFile('./photos/'.$file.'/index.html'); 
$node = $doc->getElementById('content');
```

You could do something like:

```
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$first_image_source = $images->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: hmm this breaks the function for me, maybe i just doing it wrong.

   $doc = new DOMDocument; 
   $doc->loadHTMLFile('./photos/'.$file.'/index.html'); 
   $node = $doc->getElementById('content');
   $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
   $first_image_source = $images->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

Comment: @bymem You can also loop over `$images` or check `$images->length` because the example code breaks if there is no image at all.